# Write an array to Serialport visual c++

Tags: visual-c++-2012

I am writing a program to communicate via RS232 from the PC to a microchip.

I am use to C#, but I started using Visual C++.

I get the following error:

IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function **"System::IO::Ports::SerialPort::Write"** matches the argument list argument types are: (RTC_Visual::uint8 [27U], int,RTC_Visual::uint8)

I wrote the command to write to the serial port as follows:

```
serialPort1->Write(TxStruct.u8_Buffer, 0, TxStruct.Message.u8_Length);
```

please can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and or what is the correct structure for the `serialport->write` method.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear from your question; showing a bit of code would help.
Seems that the parameter TxStruct.u8_Buffer does not match either the expected Byte[] or Char[]

I imply by the dot (.) that TxStruct is not managed?

The following works:

```
SerialPort ^myport=gcnew SerialPort;

//configures the port --ptr is a class that interacts with the user
myport->PortName="COM"+ptr->getportnumber();
myport->BaudRate=ptr->getbauds();
myport->DataBits=ptr->getdatab();
myport->StopBits=ptr->getstopb();
myport->Parity=ptr->getparity();
myport->WriteBufferSize=4096;
myport->RtsEnable=false;
myport->ReceivedBytesThreshold=256;

myport->WriteTimeout = 500;
String^ datatowrite="Data to write";
array<Byte>^ mybytes= Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes(datatowrite);

try
{
    myport->Open();
    myport->Write(mybytes,0,mybytes->Length);

}
catch (Exception^ e)
{
    //error
    MessageBox::Show( e->Message, "Port Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Exclamation );
}
```

The above encodes to UTF8 as I deduct from the parameter TxStruct.u8_Buffer.
Beware of the length of the buffer you are using and the WriteBufferSize property of the serial port. Also, a too long buffer with a handshake XonXoff might result in a timeout exception.

Hope this helps.

All the best,
Adan

Comment: I am manually loading data in to the TxBuffer, this buffer is in a struct union config. The buffer is of unsigned char type.

Comment: I am new to this website so I dont really know how to post the code

Comment: @user2866148 Well the serialport->write will either take a String^ and Byte[] or a Char[] but definitely not a struct. Your code is failing because of the use of the struct.

Comment: @user2866148 Depending on how your microchip is listening, you might want to try to load your struct data into a Byte[]. By default, the SerialPort class uses ASCIIEncoding. Seems like you want to load all the config file from the struct into the microchip at once; can you not load item by item?